# Add a picturebox array to a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I would need 100 pictureboxes and I think the easiest way to achieve this is to make an array of pictureboxes. But how would I add the definition for these? (I want the amount of pictureboxes read from a file, lets say 40 of them would have a specific image and their location set.)

I tried 
`PictureBox[] boxes = new PictureBox[100];`
but I cant use `boxes`

Comment: What did you try so far..

Comment: You can create your `PictureBoxes` dynamically at run-time and then to layout them you can add them to a `TableLayoutPanel` or a `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: A listView perhaps...?

Comment: If you want a **variable** number of boxes, then consider using a [List<PictureBox>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you did so far this answer could possibily help you.

You can access arrays of PictureBoxes like any array, in your case

`PictureBox myBox = boxes[42];`

But you have to keep in mind that when you initialize your array every element in the array is set to the default value.
For PictureBoxes this means `null`.

You might want to initialize them. You could do something like that:

```
PictureBox[] boxes = new PictureBox[100];
for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
{
    boxes[i] = new PictureBox; //set the pointer to a new PictureBox instance
    boxes[i]./*propertyToChange*/ = /*value*/;
    boxes[i].Image = Image.FromFile(@"Path\To\File.png"); //for setting its image

}

//And of course you need to add those boxes to your form ;)
//Presuming you're doing it in the form
this.Controls.AddRange(boxes);
```

I hope this helps you!